# The opposite of a Tit-for-Tat strategy

Tags: game-theory

The tit-for-tat strategy is a well-known strategy that can be applied, for example, in the Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma (IPD). Roughly, the idea is that you always repeat what the opponent did in the previous round.

I was wondering, does there exist a name for the opposite of a tit-for-tat strategy? That is, a strategy in which you always do the exact opposite of what your opponent did in the previous round.

Of course, in the IPD such a strategy wouldn't make any sense, but there may be other games where it does. Any links to papers that have investigated such strategies are welcome.

Comment: That's a very strange strategy.  I don't have a name, but it would be categorized as a _retaliation strategy_ which is a subclass of so-called _reactive strategies_.  See e.g. _Generous cooperators can outperform non-generous cooperators when replacing a population of defectors._ Kurokawa et al.  That said, Osborne and Rubinstein mentions something they call _Rewarding players who punish_ in their seminal book _A Course in Game Theory_ in the chapter on repeated games.  I don't they describe this strategy, but it's a start.  They also describe how to describe strategies in a formal language.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into these suggestions.

Comment: If you can describe a game where the strategy is natural, perhaps even a good one, it might be easier to answer.